# displaying stat_summary accurately on violin plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I just started using ggplot2 on R and have a violin plot question.

I have a data set that can be accessed here: [data](https://github.com/bgurcay/GJT-/blob/master/data.csv).

The data comes from a study of making estimations. The variables of interest are the question.no (questions), condition, estimate.no (tr.est1 or tr.est2) and  estimate.

The code below makes the plot look almost the way I want it to look at least for one question, yet the median dots generated by stat_summary() are displayed in between the "violins."

```
 v.data<-read.csv("data.csv")

 # loop through each question number
 d_ply(v.data, c("question.no"), function(d.plot){
 q.no <- v.data$question.no

 plot.q <- ggplot(d.plot,aes(condition, estimate, fill=estimate.no)) + 
   geom_violin() + 
   stat_summary(fun.y="median", geom="point") + 
   scale_y_continuous('Change Scores') + 
   scale_x_discrete("Conditions")

ggsave(filename=paste(q.no,".png",sep=""))

})
```

**My Question:** How can I make the median dots display correctly on the "violins" rather than in between them?

I searched the previous questions asked on ggplot2 on this site and looked at the ggplot2 documentation as well as other R forums but have not been able to find anything relevant.

I would appreciate any comments and suggestions as to how I can fix it. Also, if the questions I ask are already answered somewhere else, I would appreciate the links to the threads,too. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please think about simplifying your question. For example: 1. Why not provide a data set that is smaller and has already been melted. 2. Remove the plyr code, just plot one figure. 3. Simplify your ggplot call - I don't really care about your colour choice.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I simplified the code, the data and my question.

Comment: That's an improvement, but you could still remove the `ggsave` command and the `d_ply`. If you make your question short and to the point, you'll get lots of good answers quickly. If it's too long, then no-one will bother.

Answer (score 0):

`stat_summary` is limited to the variable that determines your x-axis. One way to convey the information you want would be to replace `condition` in your call to `aes` with `interaction(condition, estimate.no)`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Plotluck](https://github.com/stefan-schroedl/plotluck) is a library based on *ggplot2* that aims at automating the choice of plot type based on characteristics of 1-3 variables. For your data set, the command `plotluck(v.data, condition, estimate, question.no)` generates the following plot:

[image]

Note that the library chose to scale y logarithmically. You can override this behavior with `plotluck(v.data,condition,estimate,question.no,opts=plotluck.options(trans.log.thresh=1E20))` but it doesn't display well, and the median points look like they are all on the zero line.