# Median and quartile on violin plots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to draw some violin plots with ggplot2, but I noticed that median and first and third quartile are not automatically displayed. I believe these plots would be much more informative with this information. Does anybody know of a way to do it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I discovered this from a google search:

First, this Stack Overflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068135/displaying-stat-summary-accurately-on-violin-plots) indicates that you can add `stat_summary(fun.y="median", geom="point")` to plot the median on a violin plot as a point.

With regard to quartiles, you will likely have to write your own function for the fun.y argument above, as demonstrated on [here](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~joseff/rstudy/summer2010_ggplot2_intro.html). E.g.:

```
median.quartile <- function(x){
    out <- quantile(x, probs = c(0.25,0.5,0.75))
    names(out) <- c("ymin","y","ymax")
    return(out) 
}
```

The full code might look like this:

```
require(ggplot2)

median.quartile <- function(x){
  out <- quantile(x, probs = c(0.25,0.5,0.75))
  names(out) <- c("ymin","y","ymax")
  return(out) 
}

ggplot(iris,aes(Species,Sepal.Length))+
  geom_violin()+
  stat_summary(fun.y=median.quartile,geom='point')
```

Comment: Thanks, @spdickson for the iris example.

Answer (score 45):

One way to do this is to just put a thin box plot over the top of it.  Here's an example with the iris data:

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris,aes(Species,Sepal.Length))+geom_violin()+geom_boxplot(width=.1)
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant - I like this a lot.

Comment: Note that the order of the plots is important here to see the boxplot.

Answer (score 28):

`geom_violin` has an argument `draw_quantiles` that allows you to specify which quantiles to include. Here is an example of 1st, 2nd, and 3rd quartiles on iris.

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
geom_violin(draw_quantiles = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75))
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the quantiles are not computed on the real data but on the density estimate! See https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1986 and https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2088

Comment: what does this mean, finally? :)