# Median and quartile on advanced violin plots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

This question is for an extension of the answer to the question posed here: [Median and quartile on violin plots in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319487/median-and-quartile-on-violin-plots-in-ggplot2).

The solution works beautifully, but how would it be extended to also take the position of the violin plots into account when using options such as fill='foo'

Example:

```
require(ggplot2)

median.quartile <- function(x){
  out <- quantile(x, probs = c(0.25,0.5,0.75))
  names(out) <- c("ymin","y","ymax")
  return(out) 
}

ggplot(data=mtcars,aes(x=factor(cyl),y=drat, fill=factor(am)))+
    geom_violin() +
    stat_summary(fun.y=median.quartile,geom='point')
```

[image: Violin plot with summary]

Here the summary statistics get mixed because it does not take displacement due to fill asteric mapping into account.

Can this be fixed?

In advance - Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add `position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)` to `stat_summary()` to ensure that points are dodged according to fill values.

```
ggplot(data=mtcars,aes(x=factor(cyl),y=drat, fill=factor(am)))+
  geom_violin() +
  stat_summary(fun.y=median.quartile,geom='point',
               position = position_dodge(width = 0.9))
```

[image]

Comment: How did you know to use 0.9?

Comment: @nstjhp it seems as default value when two groups are dodged by fill for geom_violin() - found it by trying.